# range of signed binary number system

Tags: binary

I am a bit confused about the range of values for signed binary system. If I have $3$ bit to represent a number system, then number range will be given by
$-2^{n-1}$ to $2^{n-1}-1$, that is $-4$ to $+3$. Each number is listed below (using 2's complement) :

$3$  : $011$

$2$  : $010$

$1$  : $001$

$0$  : $000$

$-1$ : $111$

$-2$ : $110$

$-3$ : $101$

Here I have enlisted seven numbers. But I have a range from $-4$ to $+3$.

Where and how I can obtain $-4$. It requires four binary digit to obtain $-4$, that is  $-4$ : $1100$.

My question is how I can fulfill the range condition by having $-4$ in my three binary digit list ?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple: the only value you have left is `100` and it corresponds to -4.

You can check that the operations produce the results you want: e.g. -4 + 3 = 100 + 011 = 111 = -1.

Comment: but first bit is sign bit. 1 represents negative and last two bit represents value. So in that case -0 makes more sense than - 4 !

Comment: The lowest number is an exception to this rule. Coincidentally, your system is also mentioned by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: how the exception is handled mathematically.What is the intuition behind it?

Comment: The intuition behind it is more obvious if you look at the unsigned counterparts (-4 -> 4, -3 -> 5, etc.)